# Why can't use semi-colon before for loop in Python?

Tags: python

I can join lines in Python using semi-colon, e.g.

```
a=5; b=10
```

But why can't I do the same with for

```
x=['a','b']; for i,j in enumerate(x): print(i,":", j)
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short (yet valid) answer is simply "because the language [grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) isn't defined to allow it". As for why *that's* the case, it's hard if not impossible to be sure unless you ask whoever came up with that portion of the grammar, but I imagine it's due to readability, which is one of the goals of Python<sup>1</sup>.

Why would you ever want to write something obscure like that? Just split it up into multiple lines:

```
x = ['a','b']
for i,j in enumerate(x):
    print(i, ":", j)
```

I would argue that this variant is much clearer.

---

<sup>1</sup> From `import this`: *Readability counts.*

Comment: One use case would be to use in command line: `python -c 'import something; for ...'`

Comment: For use case from @xOneca we can use list comprehension and run multiple list comprehension for each line inside the required for loop.

E.g.: l = [1, 2, 3]; [print(x) for x in l]; [print(x*2) for x in l];

Answer (score 25):

Because the Python grammar disallows it.  See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html):

```
stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

Semicolons can only be used to separate simple statements (not compound statements like `for`).  And, really, there's almost no reason to ever use them even for that.  Just use separate lines.  Python isn't designed to make it convenient to jam lots of code onto one line.

Comment: Thanks, I'm writing some notes for students and space was short so decided to join them as I was mentioning ; at the same time anyway :)

Answer (score 5):

Because Guido van Rossum, the creator of Python, and other developers, don't actually like the "semicolons and braces" style of code formatting.

For a brief look at how they feel about these things, try:

```
from __future__ import braces
```

Statements in Python are supposed to be separated by blank lines, and compound statements in Python are supposed to be bounded by indentation.

The existence of `;` and one-line compound statements (e.g. `for i in x: print i`) are meant to be only **very limited** concessions... and you can't combine them.

Answer (score 2):

The grammar of Python does not allow this. It's a good answer, but what's the reason for it?

I think the logic behind the decision is the following: body of a for loop must be indented in order to be recognized. So, if we allow not a `simple_stmt` there, it would require a complex and easy-to-break indentation.

Comment: Good point. I think that's probably the best rationale for this particular limitation (beyond just saying "GvR hates semicolons and braces")

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```py
x=['a','b']; [print(i,":", j) for i,j in enumerate(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A compound statement consists of one or more ‘clauses’. A clause consists of a header and a ‘suite.’ The clause headers of a particular compound statement are all at the same indentation level. Each clause header begins with a uniquely identifying keyword and ends with a colon. A suite is a group of statements controlled by a clause. A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines.

```
x=['a','b'];
```

This does not justify the clause definition and thus cannot be used as a part of a compound statement. Therefore you encounter error.