# How can I embed a Python program in a bash command if it needs both a loop and an import?

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to use Python to extract info from some JSON (on a system where I can't install jq). My current approach runs afoul of the syntax restrictions described in [Why can't use semi-colon before for loop in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293128/why-cant-use-semi-colon-before-for-loop-in-python). How can I modify this code to still work in light of this limitation?

---

My current code looks like the following:

```
$ SHIFT=$(aws ec2 describe-images --region "$REGION" --filters "Name=tag:Release,Values=$RELEASE_CODE_1.2003.2")
$ echo "$SHIFT" | python -c "import sys, json; for image in json.load(sys.stdin)['Images']: print image['ImageId'];"
  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys, json; for image in json.load(sys.stdin)['Images']: print image['ImageId'];
                        ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since Python's syntax doesn't allow a `for` loop to be separated from a prior command with a semicolon, how can I work around this limitation?

Comment: BTW, personally, I'd use `jq -r '.Images[].ImageId' <<<"$SHIFT"` rather than embedding Python here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy:  File "<string>", line 1
    import sys, json;\nfor img in json.load(sys.stdin)['Images']:\n\tprint img['ImageId']
                                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: also can't install jq due to server limitations atm

Comment: the `__import__` strategy worked wonders. thank you

Comment: if you make an answer I'll gladly accept it

Comment: Hmm. Let me see about editing this to make it less duplicative so it can be re-opened -- there probably *is* room to find a distinct question in here.

Comment: @vaultah, I've tried to edit this into a distinct question, since an answer that talked about bash syntax that can compress multi-line strings into a one-liner isn't really topical on the other question, yet is applicable to the needs of the OP here. Do you agree that this is now distinct and useful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several options here:

- Pass your code as a multi-line string. Note that `"` is used to delimit Python strings rather than the original `'` here for the sake of simplicity: A POSIX-compatible mechanism to embed a literal `'` in a single-quoted string [is possible, but quite ugly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26165123/14122).

  ```
  extractImageIds() {
    python -c '
  import sys, json
  for image in json.load(sys.stdin)["Images"]:
      print image["ImageId"]
  ' "$@"
  }
  ```
- Use bash's C-style escaped string syntax (`$''`) to embed newlines, as with `$'\n'`. Note that the leading `$` is critical, and that this doesn't work with `/bin/sh`. See [the bash-hackers' wiki on ANSI C-like strings](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting#ansi_c_like_strings) for details.

  ```
  extractImageIds() { python -c $'import sys, json\nfor image in json.load(sys.stdin)["Images"]:\n\tprint image["ImageId"]' "$@"; }
  ```
- Use [`__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) to avoid the need for a separate `import` command.

  ```
  extractImageIds() { python -c 'for image in __import__("json").load(__import__("sys").stdin)["Images"]: print image["ImageId"]' "$@"; }
  ```
- Pass the code on stdin and move the input onto argv; note that this only works if the input doesn't overwhelm your operating system's allowed maximum command-line size. Consider the following example:

  ```
  extractImageIds() {
    # capture function's input to a variable
    local input=$(</dev/stdin) || return
    # ...and expand that variable on the Python interpreter's command line
    python - "$input" "$@" <<'EOF'
  import sys, json
  for image in json.loads(sys.argv[1])["Images"]:
      print image["ImageId"]
  EOF
  }
  ```

  Note that `$(</dev/stdin)` is a more efficient bash-only alternative to `$(cat)`; due to shell builtin support, it works even on operating systems where `/dev/stdin` doesn't exist as a file.

All of these have been tested as follows:

```
extractImageIds <<<'{"Images": [{"ImageId": "one"}, {"ImageId": "two"}]}'
```

To efficiently provide stdin from a variable, one could run `extractImageIds <<<"$variable"` instead. Note that the `"$@"` elements in the wrapper are there to ensure that `sys.argv` is populated with arguments to the shell function -- where `sys.argv` isn't referenced by the Python code being run, this syntax is optional.