# How to write for loop with condition in one line

Tags: python, bash

Here is the original code:

```
import site; 
import re 

for i in site.getsitepackages():
    package = re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i)
    if package is None:
        continue
    print(package.string)
```

Output:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages
```

Here is the one line code:

```
import site; import re; for i in site.getsitepackages(): package = re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i); if package is None: continue; print(package.string)
```

Output:

```
  File "/tmp/ipykernel_2984/3719293883.py", line 1
    import site; import re; for i in site.getsitepackages(): package = re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i); if package is None: continue; print(package.string)
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want to convert the above multiple lines into one line, and then run it in the bash command line:

```
python3 -c "<one line python code>"
```

Comment: Why not save the file and then run `python someFile.py` in the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why a single line? It will impact readability.

Just use a [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html):

```
python3 <<!
import site;
import re

for i in site.getsitepackages():
     package = re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i)
     if package is None:
         continue
     print(package.string)
!
```

Comment: I think it would be worth noting that this is a shell script (not a Windows batch file) and that the script is being piped to python's stdin. Python readers may not be familiar with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to join some python lines together with a semicolon, you can not do that with loops. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293128/why-cant-use-semi-colon-before-for-loop-in-python)

> Because the Python grammar disallows it. See the documentation:
>
> `stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]`
>
> Semicolons can only be used to separate simple statements (not >compound statements like for). And, really, there's almost no >reason to ever use them even for that. Just use separate lines. >ython isn't designed to make it convenient to jam lots of code >onto one line.

However, to run a loop with `python -c` you can just run it over multiple lines. For example, the command below prints out the numbers 0 - 9 on seperate lines:

```
python -c 'while i in range(10):
    print(i)
'
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the `for` command, which is not allowed to be used with the `;` operator or with more than one `:` operator in Python.

There are a few ways you could massage this sort of thing into working, but the simplest is with a clever use of list comprehensions.

```py
import re, site; [print(package.string) for i in site.getsitepackages() if (package := re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i))]
```

Which you can execute from `bash` like:

```sh
pyhton3 -c 'import re, site; [print(package.string) for i in site.getsitepackages() if (package := re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i))]'
```

The above takes advantage of the fact that `print(package.string)` only gets executed when the `if` is true. It also takes advantage of the `:=` "walrus" in-place assignment operator, which works like the normal `=` except that you can use it inside a formula or list comprehension.

You can also use a here doc, if this is in a fully-fledged `bash` script.

```sh
python3 <<!
import re
import site
for i in site.getsitepackages():
    if package := re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i):
        print(package.string)
!
```

And finally you can use in-line newlines from bash:

```sh
python -c $'import re, site\nfor i in site.getsitepackages():\n if package := re.search("^/usr/local/lib/.*/dist-packages$", i):\n  print(package.string)'
```

When you place a `$` in front of a single-quoted string, then `bash` will expand backslash escaped newlines and other backslash escapes. (Be careful when combining this with regex though!)